# Can you prevent users from reviewing your Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are interested in publishing an Alexa skill, but for legal reasons, would need to disable reviews.  Does Alexa allow skill creators to disable reviews for their skill?

Comment: Why would there be any legal reason to disable reviews? Your using someone else's services and reviews are part of that service. Plus reviews are kinda like free speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no option to do that